# Android findViewbyid из Fragment

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь использовать recycleView из фрагмента.
Для этого прописал слд. строки

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    //Change 2 to your choice because here 2 is the number of Grid layout Columns in each row.
    recyclerViewLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);

    recyclerView_Adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(context,numbers);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerView_Adapter);
```

Но проблема в том, что ругается на `Cannot resolve method 'findViewById' in 'LeftOversFragment`
на сколько я понимаю, у фрагментов надо использовать `getView().findViewById`
но в методе onCreate этот самый `getView()` у фрагментов еще не появился. Если я все правильно понял. Собственно говоря вопрос, как мне правильно написать строку `recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);`   или в каком месте, чтобы избежать ошибок этих?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте код фрагмента

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks_blanc, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Вызывайте `getView().findViewById()` в методе `onViewCreated()`